# Eclipse: "selection does not contain a main type" error when main function exists

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point

Whenever I try to launch my code, Eclipse gives me the error "selection does not contain a main type"
This is my code:

```
public class main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

    }

}
```

Here is the project tree:
[image: project tree]

for a comment: [image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Selection does not contain a main type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225177/error-selection-does-not-contain-a-main-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is excluded from the run types in Eclipse as it exists outside a source folder. Create a new source folder `src/main/java` and move the file there.

Here are the basic project source folders for Eclipse:

- `src/main/java` - Java source files
- `src/main/resources`  - Project resources, e.g. images, property files
- `src/test/java`  - Unit test Java source files
- `src/test/resources` - Test resource files

Comment: Should the images go in src as well?

Comment: Place images in `src/main/resources`. They can be loaded using `Class#getResource` later.

Comment: Sorry I'm new with eclipse, but what kind of folders should they be? I understand that there are regular and source folders, but I don't know the diffrence

Comment: Consider a source folder as a search location to look for resources for a project. Conversely regular folders are not search locations

Comment: So I do make them source folders?

Comment: You mean the folders `Maps` and `Images`? Move them both to `src/main/resources`. Those folders will be copied to the class ouput directory when the project is built.

Comment: ummm... is this supposed to happen?(see main post)