# Eclipse says "selection does not contain a main type" when there's no coding errror

Tags: java, polymorphism

When I was done with my java coding after checking there's no errors and ran it, eclipse told me that "selection does not contain a main type". I have gone through checking `public static void main(String[] args){` and it is correct. I have also searched for some similar problems others encountered, and it seems that I did not find any solutions which could fit in mine. Hope you guys can help my figure it out, will greatly appreciate if any! Here's my coding as follow:

```
import java.util.Random;

class Shape {
protected Color color;
protected Point point;

public Shape (Color color, Point point)
{ this.color = color;
this.point = point;
}
public String Type(){return " ";}
}

class Rectangle extends Shape{
public Rectangle(Color color, Point point){
    super(color, point);}

public String Type(){return "Rectangle";}
}
class Triangle extends Shape{
    public Triangle(Color color, Point point){
        super(color, point);
    }
    public String Type(){return "Triangle";}
}
class Eclipse extends Shape{
    public Eclipse(Color color, Point point){
        super(color, point);}
    public String Type(){return "Eclipse";}
        }
public class ShapeTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Color color = new Color(50, 100, 150);
        Point point = new Point(50,50);
        Shape[] theShape = {
                new Rectangle(color, point),
                new Triangle(color, point),
                new Eclipse(color, point)
        };
        Shape shapechoice;
        Random select = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
        {
            shapechoice = theShape[select.nextInt(theShape.length)];
            System.out.println("The " + (i + 1) + "type you chose is: " +       shapechoice.Type());;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all this code in a single file? or they are written in separated file you just paste them here.?

Comment: My Eclipse does not say that and happily runs your code. In other words, your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selection does not contain a main type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225177/error-selection-does-not-contain-a-main-type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is running correctly just create different files for each class and then execte the shape test class

class name-Shape.java

```
class Shape {
protected Color color;
protected Point point;

public Shape (Color color, Point point)
{ this.color = color;
this.point = point;
}
public String Type(){return " ";}
}
```

Rectangle.java

```
    class Rectangle extends Shape{
        public Rectangle(Color color, Point point){
            super(color, point);}

        public String Type(){return "Rectangle";}

}
```

Triangle.java

```
class Triangle extends Shape{
    public Triangle(Color color, Point point){
        super(color, point);
    }
    public String Type(){return "Triangle";}
}
```

Eclipse.java

```
class Eclipse extends Shape{
    public Eclipse(Color color, Point point){
        super(color, point);}
    public String Type(){return "Eclipse";}
        }
```

ShapeTest.java--- execute this class

```
public class ShapeTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Color color = new Color(50, 100, 150);
        Point point = new Point(50,50);
        Shape[] theShape = {
                new Rectangle(color, point),
                new Triangle(color, point),
                new Eclipse(color, point)
        };
        Shape shapechoice;
        Random select = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
        {
            shapechoice = theShape[select.nextInt(theShape.length)];
            System.out.println("The " + (i + 1) + "type you chose is: " +shapechoice.Type());;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no rule that says they have to be in separate files.

Comment: Thats not a rule but i am telling a better way of coding.. and its running succesfully in my eclipse

Comment: I'm successfully running OP's literal code as well.