# Selection does not contain a main type Java Eclipse

Tags: java

Code:

```
 public class TestScenario {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int episode=0;
        String fileName="test.csv";
        String predicateFile="test.txt";
        Scenario newScenario=new Scenario();
        newScenario.setPredicatefile(predicateFile);
        //newScenario.initializeScenario(1,fileName,"John Hinkle Place",5);
        //newScenario.startScenario("Accelarate","doNothing");
    }

}
```

error:

```
Selection does not contain a main type.
```

Error screenshot:
   [image]

But I clearly have a main class declared. Any suggestions on the mistake is helpful.

Comment: how `Selection` look like?

Comment: @YCF_L am not getting your question.

Comment: Selection is not define in your code, is it a class or what?

Comment: Right click your `TestScenario`  class file in eclipse, select `Run As` , and select `Java Application`. This probably happened because you clicked that green play button, but did not check out what is on the selection . You can see it by clicking dropdown arrow next to that green play button.

Comment: Sounds like you tried to run a class called "Selection" when in fact you wanted to run "TestScenario".

Comment: @ChrisParker nope i did not make that mistake. In fact I do not have a class called selection in the code.

Comment: @Jimmy Nope I did not use the green button. I did exactly what you suggested.

Comment: Then Click that 010 sign on tep left of eclipse. basically build it once and try again

Comment: Did you save the file?

Comment: @DevendraLattu yes.

Comment: Right click on the folder where you put your main class then click on Build Path --> Use as Source Folder.

Finally run your main file as java application. Hope this problem will be solved.

Taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225177/error-selection-does-not-contain-a-main-type