# trouble running java program in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm

I'm just starting out in java and I'm trying to make a greedy algorithm. The first step is to read the file.txt with the jewel values and bag weight limit and such. unfortunately I am having trouble getting the program to run. I am using eclipse and when I click run I get the following error message "the selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches". 
When I select the java greedy algorithm folder in the file tree and select run i get the following message "selection does not contain a main type". the work file and file.txt are saved in the same folder on my desktop but I wonder if the program isn't finding it. here's my code:

```
/** open and read a file, and return the lines in the file as a list of strings */
private List<String> readFile(file.txt)
{
    List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.txt));
        String line;
        while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            records.add(line);
        }
        reader.close():
        return records;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.format("Exception occurred trying to read '%s'.", file.txt);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Selection does not contain a main type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225177/error-selection-does-not-contain-a-main-type)

Answer (score 1):

A java class should have a `main` method then only you can run that.

So, your class will be like this.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

public static void main(String... args) {
    //call readFile
    List<String> someList = readFile(<pass filename here>);
    //do something here with someList
}


/** open and read a file, and return the lines in the file as a list of strings */
private static List<String> readFile(String filename)
{
    List<String> records = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line;
        while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            records.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        return records;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.format("Exception occurred trying to read '%s'.",filename );
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Note that, I marked `readFile` method as `static` which is because I am invoking it from `main` method without creating an instance of `Test` class. If you create an instance of `Test` class, and call `readFile` method on it, then you can remove `static` modifier.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but I still get the same error messages. it also says args is not correctly spelled. Is 'args' a placeholder for something?

Comment: A.Must15 incorrect spelling must be a warning. Just wondering, how are you running the code?

Comment: in eclipse. when I select just the individual greedy file and click run it says the selection can't be launched and there are no recent launches. when i select the full file tree and click run as java application it says selection does not contain a main type.

Comment: Are there any compilation errors in the code. Or, if you used the above code which clearly has a main method

Comment: I don't think there are any errors but to be safe I removed all my code and used yours. got the same result.

Comment: I am not really sure, what is happening there as it runs properly for me. Just guessing, are imports missing? or if the class name and filename are different? I have added the imports in above code as well. So, all you should change is this `<pass filename here>`

Comment: I tried adding the import stuff but I still get the same result. side note: is there like a website or something with a list of everything that can be imported into java?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a method named `void main(String[] args)`.
This is the method that gets called when you start your program.
In this main method you can call your readFile method, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  readFile();
}
```

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Code
}`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ...
}
```

There you can call your function.