# Error: Selection does not contain main type

Tags: java, eclipse

I've imported some packages (`com.g52aim` and `com.g52aim.lab00`) into a new Java project in Eclipse. I select the file I wish to run (`Labrunner_00_Runner.java`), and then I get this message when I click run:

`Error: Selection does not contain main type`

Yes I have looked through all the answers on this question: [Error: Selection does not contain a main type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225177/error-selection-does-not-contain-a-main-type)

None of the solutions from that question have worked, so I don't know what to do.
Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image: Error message in Eclipse]

Comment: `lab00` does not look like a `package`, more like a folder. Probably this is a problem.

Comment: @MichałZiober Yes, whenever I create a package called "com.g52aim.lab00", it just seems to automatically become a folder within "com.g52aim"... Not sure what to do about that either.

Comment: What's the class declaration look like? Can you show us the rest of its source?