# Error: Selection does not contain a main type; answers to similar questions not working

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I'm using Java Eclipse 2019.3, and no matter what I try I can't get this program to run. It's giving me the 'Selection does not contain a main type' error message.

Things I've tried:

- using the formatting 'clean up' option
- changing the class name to match that of the file
- changing the class name to match that of the file and the folder (file is currently named Main.java, class on code is Main)
- updating and restarting Eclipse as a whole
- capitalizing and uncapitalizing 'main'
- running from the 'Run as' option and clicking 'Java application' manually
- creating an entirely new project, copy-and-pasting the code into a new class, and attempting to run it again

Please help, I have no idea what's happening even after checking all the other answers on this forum and others. This is the code:

```
package australianvoting295;

import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Main {

   static void australianvoting295 (int[][] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number of cases: ");
        int numberofcases = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Number of candidates");
        int numberofcandidates = in.nextInt();
        if (numberofcandidates <= 20) {
            int numberofballotoptions = in.nextInt();
            if (numberofballotoptions <= 1000) {
                enterCandidateNames(numberofcandidates);
            }
        }
    }

    static void enterCandidateNames(int numberofcandidates) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] numberofcandidatesarray = new String[numberofcandidates];
        int counter = 0;
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            while (counter < numberofcandidates) {
                System.out.println("Enter candidate name:");
                String candidatename = in.next();
                numberofcandidatesarray[numberofcandidates] = candidatename;
                counter++;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...you know you need a main method to run the program right?

Comment: The error is informing you that you must include a main *method*: include the line `public static void main(String args[]) {}` in your class in order for it to compile, and then add whatever statements into that method you would like for the program to run, such as making a call to `enterCandidateNames` via `enterCandidateNames(5);`, for example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Selection does not contain a main type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225177/error-selection-does-not-contain-a-main-type)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying too many things to resolve a rather simple error. As Eclipse tells you, if you try to run a class, it should contain a method with the signature

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

Go through this Hello world [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) for more understanding.

Comment: Oh god, I can't believe I missed that...shifted some things around and it worked. Thanks!