# Eclipse can't run a demo app because it can't find main type, even though it exists

Tags: java, eclipse

I last wrote java 10 years ago, but coming back to it today, I can't get started with a demo app that I've been given.  I'm using Eclipse and when I right click on the class that does have the main function defined, it says "Selection does not contain a main type", see images.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks .

[image: Trying to run java application]
[image: response: Selection does not contain a main type]

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16225177/2670892

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the main/java folder and use the Build-Path submenu to designate it as a Source Folder. Only top-level classes with a valid `main` method *and located in in Source Folders* are runnable as Java Applications.