# Why am I getting the error 'Main method not found in class' even though I defined the main method in my Java program with inheritance?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods, program-entry-point

```
package code.now;


class Test {
    public void fun() {
        System.out.println("Coding Ninjas");
    }
}

class Derived extends Test {
    
    public void fun() {
        System.out.println("Coding Ninjas");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived obj = new Derived();
        obj.fun();
    }
}
```

i'm trying to execute this code and running into the below error

"Error: Main method not found in class code.ninja.Derived, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application"

but I already defined the main method and also tried to check for any syntax and spelling mistakes but still the code is returning the error.

Comment: It looks like you have put both classes in one file. Don't do that. `Derived` goes in `Derived.java` and `Test` goes in `Test.java`. Also, you currently overload the single function from `Test` in `Derived` (and just duplicated the code when you did so). That is both confusing and pointless. Also your declared package is `code.now` but your error message is from `code.ninja`.

Comment: Additionally, I think the class containing `main` should be `public`

Comment: @QBrute not required.

Comment: Using eclipse or intelij?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Selection does not contain a main type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225177/error-selection-does-not-contain-a-main-type)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - it is not pointless, i'm just a beginner and learning the implementation with some basic examples. I cannot comment on others capabilities ...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you are right about  the package name mismatch in the error and the code. I might have made a typo in writing the package name in code snippet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I faced the same before. Your code is  good. No issues. Problem with IDE config.

For Eclipse https://stackoverflow.com/a/75637946/11962586

UPDATE - Try this way

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If it's a dupe mark it as a dupe; if it isn't, link-only answers aren't great.

Comment: @Dave Newton , I couldn't see the duplicate option.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but: 1) we don't know if it's the right answer because we don't know how the OP is running the code, 2) duplicates are the first option listed when we vote to close a question, and 3) link-only answers are not how SO works *(and if the answer is an SO link it's a dupe by definition)*.

Comment: I tried running this code. works good. The problem is with IDE. Could you please tell me how to mark it as duplicate?

Comment: You're missing what I'm saying: we don't know if the OP is even **using** an IDE *(or which one if they are)*. Underneath the question are links: `Share Edit Follow Close Flag`. Click "Close" to close the question *(a vote to close, actually)*. Find the duplicate question from the list provided, by searching, or by pasting a link. Click the "Vote to Close" button.

Comment: Thanks for assisting. I raised request to close.

Comment: No problem :thumbs-up:

Comment: @DaveNewton , the reason i posted a new question cause the answers in the suggested questions didn’t fix my problem. Neither could i comment cause I don't have enough privileges to comment on others answers. So the only logical option for me is to post a new question as the answers on the other questions didn't help me

Comment: @Goutham The dupe comments were directed at the poster of this answer.

Comment: @Goutham you got those privileges now. Have fun. I faced the same. We need more upvotes to  access those privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.

I think I found the issue. There are two files in the same package

> package code.ninja;

```
> Main.java
> Deriveded.java
```

- Main.java ( this has a class name Derived ), so when I tried to create a new java class with Derived.java it's throwing error, but after I changed the class to Deriveded.java, the errors are gone.
- Deriveded.java (previously it was Derived.java )

[Main.java program in the same package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onYxp.png)

[Deriveded.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFGcX.png)